# HTML: Оборачивание элементов ссылками

Tags: html

Допустим, мы хотим сделать элемент (заголовок, картинку в контейнере, блок в сайдбаре и т. д.) ссылкой. Это можно реализовать по крайней мере следующими методами:

- Обернуть выше указанные элементы в `<a>`. Вероятно, это технически не совсем правильно, т. к. `<a>` не рекомендуется использоваться в качестве контейнера.
- Обернуть `<a>` только содержимое контейнера, но не сам контейнер. Думаю так  уже правильнее, но жду Ваших аргументов.
- Вообще не добавлять никаких ссылок в HTML, а добавить нужные редиректы по клику через `jQuery`. Изящно или нет, вопрос спорный; опять же жду, что Вы скажете на основе своего опыта.

Какой из указанных Выше методом является оптимальным?

P. S. Только пожалуйста, не упротребляйте словосочетание "более оптимальный" - "оптимальный" только один.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самым верным методом будет первый. В `<a>`, в отличие от остальных строчных элементов, можно размещать блочные элементы - это [нормальная практика в HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element). Карточки товаров, превьюшки фотографий с кратким описанием, заголовки (для создания якорей) - всё это безболезненно может быть обернуто элементом `<a>`.

Вы можете использовать и второй метод, но это не повлияет ни на семантику, ни на UX (если только в худшую сторону), но под это дело придется выделить больше CSS.

Третий метод следует использовать чуть менее, чем никогда. За это вам никто не скажет спасибо: ни поисковые системы, ни пользователи с ограниченными возможностями.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ, всё хорошо аргументировали!